# react update forever loop componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to the documentation:

> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
    this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```

Now my method looks like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log("Fitting update");
    this.getDataBasedOnMessurements();
}

getDataBasedOnMessurements() {
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + 'configurator/getFittingData', {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.props.messurements)
    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    }).then((myJson) => {
        this.setState({data: myJson.fittingExtra})
    });
};
```

The problem with this is that since the state is being updated the `ComponentDidUpdate` is now in a forever loop
[image]

So what is the right way of calling an API and updating the state when the props on the component is being updated?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what the business logic is here, but since it seems that the API request only depends on `this.props.messurements`, it's likely that you only want to fire that when that particular prop has changed. (And if the reason for doing something isn't that some prop or state might have changed, then why do it in `componentDidUpdate`?)

Comment: You are passing values (mesurements) then do as the example and only request and set state when the parameter changed compared to last time (remember that `{}` !== `{}`). All of this has been replaced with [use effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: `setState` calls `render`, which calls `componentDidMount` which in your case again calls `setState`. Hence the cycle. You could use `componentWillReceiveProps`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right place for calling the API is in componentDidMount() and updating the state is in componentDidUpdate.

But as I can see you are not using any reducer or dispatching any function. You are directly setting the data after getting the response instead of updating the props. So, you can remove the componentDidUpdate() method and just call the API in componentDidMount()

Please check this code,

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataBasedOnMessurements();
}

getDataBasedOnMessurements() {
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + 'configurator/getFittingData', {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.props.messurements)
    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    }).then((myJson) => {
        this.setState({data: myJson.fittingExtra})
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code, `getDataBasedOnMessurements` function will be called for each update of props as there is no condition in your `componentDidUpdate` code. You have to compare the props to get the specific situation where you want to trigger the api call.

Answer (score 1):

You should put a conditional to stop the infinite loop in it. In this case, I think you are depending on `this.props.messurements` whether to make a call.

The example below is taken from the official React Documentation tweaked to your needs based on the code snippets you have provided us.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.messurements !== prevProps.messurements) {
    this.getDataBasedOnMessurements();
  }
}
```